# Graphql, nodejs, how to resolve non-root level query field based on if it is queried?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'd like to resolve a field called 'outstandingBalance' in Client type. If front-end query:

```
query {
  Client {
    id
    name
    outstandingBalance
  }
}
```

The resolver function for outstandingBalance is expensive to run. If front-end query:

```
query {
  Client {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Then, don't trigger the resolver for 'outstandingBalance'. I have basic understanding of graphql and read most of [its official document](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/). But have not seen an answer to this pattern, or this way of using Graphql is not allowed?

**Question**
Is there a thing called "Nont-root level resolver" for graphql? like the 'outstandingBalance' field in Client type?

**Question**: How to implement in graphql? Especially using resolver:

```
async function outstandingBalance(obj, args, context, info) {

  console.log('called...')

}
```

to query one field in one type based on if this field is queried?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but if you do not query the `outstandingBalance` from the client side, the resolver will not be called.

Comment: As above - for docs example query `{
  human(id: 1002) {
    name } }` won't call `appearsIn` and `starships` resolvers.

Comment: But I want `outstandingBalance` inside client. Is it possible? Just like sharships inside human as a field.